# Regex Find and Replace using line numbers condition in editplus

Tags: regex, editplus

I have a huge text file with over 20K lines of content. I am using editplus 4.0 version to achieve my desired result.

**What I want to do is;**

I want to insert/append a keyword, randomly in the content. Now, the condition is, I want to insert my keyword once for every 60 lines.

If I achieve this, next I have another app which can split my huge content into multiple lines based on line count, which is 60 in this case.

So, end of the day I will have my content into multiple text files and every file includes my keyword which I am going to use it for blog posting.

Please suggest me if I can do this with editplus, other ways of achieving the same will also welcome.

I tried lot of options but no luck.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: No you can't do that using editplus. You should do it in a programming language of your choice. Basically open the file, add your content every x line number close the file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jorge, can you through some php code to do this.

Comment: Sorry, no, you have to show some effort first. StackOverflow is not a free service code. Try it yourself first, then, if you get stuck with your code you edit your question with it.

Comment: @MuhammadAzhar have you tried something like find: `/((?:^[^\n]*\n){59}^[^\n]*)/gm` replace: `\1KEYWORD` ([see demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPytkp/1))

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK editplus doesn't work with regex.

I suggest you to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), with it you can do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `((?:[^\r\n]*\R){60})`
- Replace with: `$1KEYWORD\n`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Don't forget to select `Regular expression` in search mode.